# Is OpenSSL (not mod_ssl) Installed by WampServer 3.2.2 or Apache?

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, openssl

Is OpenSSL (the "stand-alone" version, not the Apache mod_ssl module) installed by WampServer 3.2.2 or Apache?  I'm using WampServer 3.2.2 on Windows 10 as a web site development platform and I see that both OpenSSL and mod_ssl are present in the Apache install folder.  Does anyone know whether WampServer installs OpenSSL or the Apache installer installs it during WampServer installation?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed via the WampServer forum that the Apache installer installs the "stand alone" version of OpenSSL (which is the file openssl.exe).